# segmentation error coming out?

Tags: c, string

I was trying to concatenate 2 strings without using `strcat`, but I am getting a runtime error.  Please, someone help me out here...

Also, is this statement `q=q+len;` correct? Can we add a variable to a pointer??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void xstrcat(char*,char*);
int main()
{
    char source[]="folks";
    char target[30]="hello";
    xstrcat(target,source);
    printf("%s",source);
    printf("%s",target);
    return 0;
}

void xstrcat(char*p,char*q)
{
    int len=0;
    len=strlen(q);
    q=q+len;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        *q=*p;
        q++;
        p++;
    }
    *q='\0';
}
```

Comment: You should append `source` to `target`, but it seems that you are doing the other way around.

Comment: What about debugging? Did you try to debug your code? Your code contains an obvious error that would be immediately revealed by a debugging session. This is not supposed to be a "debug my code for me" place.

Comment: Also, if your are not sure about the validity of `q=q+len` expression, how come you are using it in our code. Is this code actually yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some mistakes in your implementation:

1 - You are accessing random memory. Once you don't have a `/0` in your string.

```
while(*p!='/0')
```

must be:

```
while(*p!='\0')
```

Note the slash **\**.

2 - You are overwriting random memory when try to add `*p` into `*q`. You must create a new variable with enough space for store them.

> Also, is this statement q=q+len; correct? Can we add a variable to a
>   pointer??

Yes. [It's a pointer arithmetic expression.](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing target as the first parameter in function call, but it seems that the function tries to use the second parameter as the target. So, maybe you would just need yo switch places of parameters in the function call.

Another thing is that you are using slash instead of backslash when escaping the null character. So, change '/0' to '\0'.

Regarding adding int to pointer: in your case in the function that type of pointer arithmetic is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things, first, you need to check against `\0` and not `/0`

```
while(*p!='\0')
```

But also, you are trying to add a string to a string literal, which will cause undefined behaviour. Switch

```
xstrcat(target,source);
```

to

```
xstrcat(source, target);
```

Finally, the last line in `xstrcat` should be changed to

```
*q='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting the memory.

You are concatenating to `source` which does not have enough memory to hold concatenated characters.

You may want to reverse definition of `source` and `target`.
i.e.

```
char source[30] = "folks";
char *target = "hello";
```

Or

call `xstrcat` as `xstrcat(source, target);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your code in the below line:

```
xstrcat(target,source);
```

It should be

```
xstrcat(source,target);
```

or in your xstrcat function, try considering the first parameter as target and second as source.